# отрисовка кнопки в Android

Tags: java, android, button

Подскажите,необходимо отрисовывать кнопку в android(заливка цветом),используя значения из поля ввода, значения от 0 до 1(где 0 кнопка не залита,0.5 - половина заливки,1-полностью и тд).

Comment: `0.5 - половина заливки` - по вертикали, по горизонтали? Прозрачность?

Comment: заливка по горизонтали,слева>направо

Answer (score 0):

C проблемой справился силами этого парня [GitHub ProgressButton](http://github.com/pavlofff/ProgressButton)